# Lxml: Return a part of the xml file as string

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, lxml

I am parsing my xml file using lxml parser which looks like this:

```
    # some elements above
    <contact>
       <phonenumber>
            #something
       </phonenumber>
    </contact>
```

I want to be able to return only a part of the xml file.

Like Suppose if I am on phonenumber, I want lxml to return the everything between   as a string .

I dont want to return textb/w phonenumber but the entire string :

```
    <phonenumebr>something</phonenumber>
```

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

To print a part of the XML tree, you can use `lxml.etree.tostring`. On Python 2:

```
In [1]: from lxml.etree import tostring, parse

In [2]: tree = parse('test.xml')

In [3]: elem = tree.xpath('//phonenumber')[0]

In [4]: print tostring(elem)
<phonenumber>
            something
       </phonenumber>
```

For more information you can refer to the ["Serialisation" section of the `lxml` tutorial.](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#serialisation)